# Expectation of function of random variable

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, expected-value

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two independent identically distributed  random variables with range $[0,100]$. And let $ g(X_1) =X_1$ for $X_1>c$ and $g(X_1) =X_2$ for $X_1<c$ where $c$ is a constant.

What would be the Expectation of $g(X_1)$. This is what I have tried so far using the law of total expectation I get 
 \begin{align}
E[g(X_1)]&=E[g(X_1) |X_1>c] P(X_1>c) +E[g(X_1) |X_1<c]P(X_1<c)\\
        &=E[X_2] P(X_1>c) +E[X_1|X_1<c]P(X_1<c) 
 \end{align}

The rest can be computed given the probability distribution. What I don't understand is the justification of this? Does law of expectation remain valid for this even though the output of the function is not a random variable but two random variables. I have only seen this law applied if it just depends on one random variable not two so I am not sure about this.

Comment: Of course law of total expectation is valid, but your second equality in $E[g(X_1)]$ is not.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: If the first equality holds I don't see why the second one shouldn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way (without assuming that $0<\mathsf{P}(X_1>c)<1$) would be writing the expectation of $Z\equiv X_21\{X_1\le c\}+X_11\{X_1>c\}$ as
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}Z&=\mathsf{E}[X_21\{X_1\le c\}]+\mathsf{E}[X_11\{X_1>c\}] \\
&=\mathsf{E}[X_2]\mathsf{P}(X_1\le c)+\mathsf{E}[X_11\{X_1>c\}].
\end{align}

Comment: @Thanks. If you have the time could you please also look into this tweet https://twitter.com/gregeganSF/status/1201376108970536961?s=09  and the solution the OP provides. This was the motivation behind this question. When the OP computes the Expectation of xfinal in the solution which is the same as that of $g(X1)$  here he gets a different result .i can't justify how he gets a different result there. Do you know whether that expression he obtains Is valid.?

Comment: @Human Actually, I don't see any issue with those formulas.

Comment: yeah you are right I made a mistake. Just one more thing  I can't understand. Could you please elaborate on how you got E[X2 1 x1<c] =E[X2] P(X1<c)?

Comment: I think that it E[X2 1 x1<c] should be just E[X2] since X2 and X1 are independent. I don't understand why it would be multiplied by the probability

Comment: Independence and the fact that $\mathsf{E}1_A=\mathsf{P}(A)$.

Comment: Yes that's makes sense I didn't think of 1 as a proper function before but now I get it. Thanks alot.